# Extract JSON from a string with plain text and JSON

Tags: bash

Given the following string:

```
[2018-07-30 12:32:26] local.INFO: {"type":"canonical-log-line","http_method":"POST","http_path":"\/foo","http_status":200,"duration":1.720768928527832,"ts":"2018-07-30 12:32:26"}
```

How would you select only the JSON object? eg:

```
{"type":"canonical-log-line","http_method":"POST","http_path":"\/foo","http_status":200,"duration":1.720768928527832,"ts":"2018-07-30 12:32:26"}
```

Comment: Looks like a simple job for [cut](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use sed.

```
string='[2018-07-30 12:32:26] local.INFO: {"type":"canonical-log-line","http_method":"POST","http_path":"\/foo","http_status":200,"duration":1.720768928527832,"ts":"2018-07-30 12:32:26"}'

echo $string | sed 's/^.*{/{/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (if you can pipe the output into a python variable and use python) as long as your string only contains 1 pair of open/closing brackets:

```
import json
import subprocess

#command below is the bash command you want to run:
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).decode()
# overriding output as i dont know what bash command you're running
output = '[2018-07-30 12:32:26] local.INFO: {"type":"canonical-log-line","http_method":"POST","http_path":"\/foo","http_status":200,"duration":1.720768928527832,"ts":"2018-07-30 12:32:26"} '

json_str = output[output.index('{'): output.index('}')+1]
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
print(json_obj['type'])
```